# Substring - argument out of range exception - startIndex parameter

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, substring

Assume that I have the following string in TextBox1: FPO100200%10&FORD*

Now, i have 2 more textboxes that gets data from substrings of textbox1. I have the following code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Function textmoves(mytext As String, indexchar As String)
    Dim Index As Integer = mytext.IndexOf(indexchar)
    Return Index
End Function
Private Sub Splittext()
    Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text
    TextBox2.Text = text.Substring(0, textmoves(text, "%"))
    TextBox3.Text = text.Substring(textmoves(text, "%"), textmoves(text, "&"))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Splittext()
End Sub
```

End Class

Im trying to get in texbox2 the substring FPO100200, then in texbox3 the substring 10.

As soon as I added the line with textbox3, it threw me an argument out of range error. Can you tell me what im doing wrong? Thanks alot!

LE: Also, how can I make that textboxes to populate with data when text changed in textbox1, automatically, without pressing the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter is length, not end position. The reason the first expression worked with position is that the initial index is zero.

To get `"10"` use

```
TextBox3.Text = text.Substring(textmoves(text, "%")+1, textmoves(text, "&")-textmoves(text, "%")-1)
```

or better

```
Dim pos As Integer = textmoves(text, "%")
TextBox2.Text = text.Substring(0, pos)
TextBox3.Text = text.Substring(pos+1, textmoves(text, "&")-pos-1)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/YEUlPV)

Comment: Yes, now i see the mistake. Thank you. I also added an edit to my original question, but i quess now its too late.

Comment: @CatalinCernat Since the last edit is not in line with the rest of the question, the best way to get an answer is to post a new question. Say that you have your `Splittext` working, that you have attached it to `Button1_Click`, and now you'd like to get rid of the button. Link to this question, and post an updated code. This should get you a nice answer that wouldn't fit in a comment (essentially, you would need to listen to text change event of text box 1, and catch exceptions in `Splittext`).

Answer (score 1):

Your second parameter is the Index of the & when you start at index 0 but you're begining at the index of %. So you need to substract %Index from &Index.

```
TextBox3.Text = text.Substring(textmoves(text, "%"), textmoves(text, "&") - textmoves(text, "%"))
```

Comment: Now i see my mistake. Thank you. Although i dont get 10, i get %10 as result. The answer proposed bellow works 100%,